# CordaRPCClient throws error while connecting to Node running inside Docker container

Tags: corda, activemq-artemis

```
Following error is being thrown, same client works fine with the node running as a java service on the system.
```

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyConnector.createConnection(NettyConnector.java:800) ~[artemis-core-client-2.6.3.jar!/:2.6.3]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl.openTransportConnection(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:1046) [artemis-core-client-2.6.3.jar!/:2.6.3]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl.createTransportConnection(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:1086) [artemis-core-client-2.6.3.jar!/:2.6.3]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl.establishNewConnection(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:1297) [artemis-core-client-2.6.3.jar!/:2.6.3]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl.getConnection(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:901) [artemis-core-client-2.6.3.jar!/:2.6.3]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl.getConnectionWithRetry(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:797) [artemis-core-client-2.6.3.jar!/:2.6.3]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl.reconnectSessions(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:746) [artemis-core-client-2.6.3.jar!/:2.6.3]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl.failoverOrReconnect(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:616) [artemis-core-client-2.6.3.jar!/:2.6.3]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl.handleConnectionFailure(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:506) [artemis-core-client-2.6.3.jar!/:2.6.3]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl.handleConnectionFailure(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:499) [artemis-core-client-2.6.3.jar!/:2.6.3]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl.connectionException(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:370) [artemis-core-client-2.6.3.jar!/:2.6.3]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyConnector$Listener$2.run(NettyConnector.java:1073) [artemis-core-client-2.6.3.jar!/:2.6.3]
```

Comment: @Justin Bertram is this a bug or i am doing something wrong.

Comment: The NPE looks to be a bug, but I can't see any way that variable would be `null` under normal circumstances. I'm an ActiveMQ developer and don't really work with Corda so I'm not sure what the underlying use-case is.

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like the entire stacktrace is within Artemis and is outside the scope of Corda.

However, it's possible that the Corda node trying to make the connection is misconfigured somehow and so the network that nodes are trying to communicate over does not work correctly; that is where I would investigate as it could be a more obscure issue that is causing artemis to croak.

if you could share your node configuration here that would be good to verify that the network config is correct.